# Service can't access a shared folder while the same console app can (FileSystemWatcher object)

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

i wrote a windows service that should monitor a folder and do stuff as soon as a file is copied/moved/created inside that specific folder. My problem is that while I execute the program in a console I'm able to read a shared folder without problems (local, shared, using ip or UNC) instead if I run the same code as a service (with the same user credentials, other user credentials or network service credentials) I'm not able to see the folder. The environment is windows, the specific machine win server 2008R2 the machine is in a domain.

I tried to use this class DirectoryInfo to check the actual path, and as before exists when executed as console and not exist when executed as a service. What am I missing? Also when I execute the service with different credential I'm not able to interact with the server, Is there a way to fix this?

Same behavior on my local machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you setting the Log On as account in the Properties Log On tab of the service?

Comment: Correct, to set the user I'm setting it there

Comment: Does that user have the permissions to run as a service? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794944(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Yep both of them, the group has been added the first time i tried to run the service. And on local folders the service is working fine.

Comment: Once the service runs is it authenticating inside your code?

Comment: Also the accounts that are running the service are they domain or local accounts?

Comment: the accounts are both domain accounts, no in the code i'm not authenticating again.

Comment: What i mean is alright if you can't access the folder, but not even being able to recognize the path is a little bit too much.

Comment: You seem to set it up right and you should ask on SO. Might be a programming issue from what I remember from my .NET days things didn't work right when trying to run them as a Service and sometimes little changes were needed.

Comment: One last test, can you run the service as a domain admin?

Comment: No that can't do, i have access only to this 2 users, I tried the network service user too but no luck

Comment: Well I'm not saying always run as domain admin, just as a temporary test. Also the Network Service won't work as it passes the computer account credentials to a remote server. So unless you added the computer account on the other server or group then it definitely won't work.

Comment: So you are saying to add the user that I run the service under as admin on the machine where I'm sharing the service? So what's the difference between running it as a console app and a service?

Comment: Yes the user account that you are using to run the Service has to have the right permissions to the folder on the remote server.

Comment: I'm still confused. I am able to open the shared folder from run \\server\folder path. I'm able to run my code from a console application and the folder works in read/write (with the appropriate user). When I run the code as service the folder is nowhere to be found and the service throws an exception.

Comment: That is indeed really odd... Are you trying with the IP in the code or just a hostname? Have you tried the full FQDN? Also what about going via a mapped drive?

Comment: Yes, same behavior, the service is not able to locate the folder while the command line app is working perfectly fine(same machine same user)

Comment: Hi George, you were right I will need the service user as local user on the machine with the shared folder, otherwise the service will not be able to connect :S I was really confused about it. Thank you for your help!